# Alinear dos o mas elementos verticalmente con bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un título y un formulario en línea dentro de un div 
necesito que estos queden alineados de forma vertical y horizontal con bootstrap 4. Utilicé las clases align-items-center y justify-content center funciona pero queda muy separado el titulo de el formulario quiero que quede inmediatamente debajo pero en el centro.

Este es mi código

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid ">
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fondo">
        <h3 class="text-center  mb-">Suscríbase Aquí </h3>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group my-2">
            <label for="" class="mx-2">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa tú nombre">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group my-2">
            <label for="" class="mx-2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa tú email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group my-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es quitar la mayor cantidad de espacio entre el título y el formulario, se puede utilizar la clase `mb-0` en el h3 del título, que equivale a margen inferior igual a 0, y la clase `mt-0` en los contenedores de campos del formulario, esta clase equivale a margen superior igual a 0.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid ">
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fondo">
        <h3 class="text-center  mb-0">Suscríbase Aquí </h3>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group mt-0">
            <label for="" class="mx-2">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa tú nombre">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-0">
            <label for="" class="mx-2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa tú email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias Shaz tambien pude solucionarlo con la clase flex-column en el contenedor padre.